# Processing ActiveRecord::Reflections -- some model reflections coming up empty (Rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails & ActiveRecord 4.2.1, Ruby 2.2.0

EDIT: Please note this question is mostly looking for a discussion of how the Reflections aspect of ActiveRecord works in order to better understand AR and Rails.

I am working on a Concern that looks into an ActiveRecord model's associations and creates callbacks based on those associations.  Tests on individual files or examples pass.  However, when testing the full suite or running the dev server, it fails because certain models return nil for reflections.  The gist:

```
module CustomActivityMaker
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    # @param {Array[Symbols]} assns
    # 'assns' params is a list of a model's associations
    def create_activity_for(assns)

      assns.each do |assn|
        r = self.reflect_on_association(assn)
        if r.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection)
          # For a through association, we just track the creation of the join table.
          # byebug
          r.source_reflection.klass  # <== source_reflection unexpectedly ends up being nil
        else
          r.klass
        end
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Invoked like so:

```
# models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :phone_numbers
  has_many :checklists
  has_many :checklist_items, through: :checklists

  create_activity_for :checklist_items

  ...
end

# models/checklist.rb
class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  has_many :checklist_items
  ...
end

# models/checklist_item.rb
class ChecklistItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :checklist
  has_one :matter, through: :checklist

  ...
end
```

The error is shown in the comment note in CustomActivityMaker.  When using byebug, the variable r is an ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection. The call to source_reflection should be an ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection, with 'klass' giving me the ChecklistItem class.

However :source_reflection comes up nil.  Using byebug to inspect the error, the through class Checklist does not have any reflections:

```
Checklist.reflections  # <== {}
```

Of course, this is not the result if I make an inspection in the console or when running an individual test.

I'm not understanding the Rails loading process, and how and when it builds ActiveRecord reflections, and when and how I can reliably access them.  Any insight?

Comment: sorry, what is `klass`? Never mind, looked it up... I just can't delete comment on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any resources to guide me through Rails' inner-workings, so instead I went to look at a popular gem that likewise needs to parse through ActiveRecord::Reflections, [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), since it too would likely have to deal with Rails not loading things as it wished. There, I [found](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/6c6e45b23f464bd0bb92ae05a4284b72b017be21/lib/active_model/serializer/concerns/associations.rb):

```
included do
    ...

    extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
    autoload :Association
    autoload :Reflection
    autoload :SingularReflection
    autoload :CollectionReflection
    autoload :BelongsToReflection
    autoload :HasOneReflection
    autoload :HasManyReflection
  end
```

Adding this to my concern solved my issues. From the ActiveSupport::Autoload [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Autoload.html): "This module allows you to define autoloads based on Rails conventions (i.e. no need to define the path it is automatically guessed based on the filename) and also define a set of constants that needs to be eager loaded".